If $(\cfrac{a}{2}x-ae+e^a)\ln x\ge e(x-1)$ for all $x\ge 1$, find the range of $a$.
If $(\cfrac{a}{2}x-ae+e^a)\ln x\ge e(x-1)$ for all $x\ge 1$, find the range of $a$.
What I have tried:
Assume $a=0$,  the inequality becomes $\ln x \ge e(x-1)$ which is false since $\ln x \le x-1$
Assume $a<0$, let  $(\cfrac{a}{2}x-ae+e^a)\ln x=0$,  we get $x=2e-\cfrac{2e^a}{a}$ or $1$.
Since $2e-\cfrac{2e^a}{a}>1$, the inequality doesn't hold.
It can be concluded that $a \in (0, +\infty)$.
But I can't find the exact range of $a$.

Let $f(x,a)=\left(\frac{a}{2}x-ae+e^a\right)\ln x$. Note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\left(\frac{x}{2}-e+e^a\right)\ln x$, which is nonnegative for $x\geq 1$ and $a\geq 1$. Hence, the continuous function $f(x,a)$ is nondecreasing on $a$ for this range, so if we find some $a'\geq 1$ that satisfies the inequality, it is satisfied for all $a\in[a',\infty)$.
We claim the inequality is satisfied if and only if $a\in[2,\infty)$. You've already shown the $a\leq 0$ case, so we assume $a>0$.
Note that when $a=2$, we have $f(x,2)=(x-2e+e^2)\ln x$. Let $g(x)=f(x,2)-e(x-1)$. We aim to show that $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [1,\infty)$. We have $g'(x)=\ln x+1+\frac{e^2-2e}{x}-e$, which has a root at $x=e$. We also have $g''(x)=\frac{x-e^2+2e}{x^2}$, so $g(x)$ is concave up from $e^2-2e$ onwards. This means $x=e$ is a local minimum for $x\in[e^2-2e,\infty)$. But the minimum is just $g(e)=0$, so $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in[e^2-2e,\infty)$. Now, for $x\in [1,e^2-2e)$, note that $g(1)=0$ and $g(e^2-2e)>0$. Since $g(x)$ is a continuous concave down function on this range, it must lie above the lie connecting $(1,0)$ and $(e^2-2e,g(e^2,2e))$, which is positive. Hence, $g(x)\geq 0$ here too, so $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in[1,\infty)$.
Since the inequality is satisfied for $a=2$, it is satisfied for all $a\in[2,\infty)$.
We will now show that for all $a<2$, we have $f(e,a)<e(e-1)$, breaking the inequality at $x=e$. Note that $f(e,a)=e^a-\frac{ae}{2}$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\vert_{x=e}=e^a-\frac{e}{2}$, which is positive for $a>\ln\frac{e}{2}$. Since $f(e,2)=e(e-1)$, we have $f(e,a)<f(e,2)=e(e-1)$ for all $a\in\left[\ln\frac{a}{2},2\right)$. Moreover, the negative derivative on $a\in\left[0,\ln\frac{e}{2}\right)$ tells us that $f(e,a)$ achieves its maximum at $a=0$ on this range, which is $\frac{e}{2}<e(e-1)$. Thus, $f(e,a)<f(e,0)<e(e-1)$ for all $a\in(0,2)$, breaking the inequality at $x=e$, as desired.

The OP has obtained $a > 0$.
We let $x = \mathrm{e}$ to obtain
$\frac{a}{2}\mathrm{e} - a\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^a \ge \mathrm{e}(\mathrm{e} - 1),$
or
$$\mathrm{e}^{a-1} - \frac12(a-1) \ge \mathrm{e} - \frac12$$
which results in $a \ge 2$.
(Note: If $0 < a \le 1$,
we have $\mathrm{e}^{a-1} - \frac12(a-1) \le 1 + \frac12 < \mathrm{e} - \frac12$.
If $a > 1$, letting $g(a) := \mathrm{e}^{a-1} - \frac12(a-1) - (\mathrm{e} - \frac12)$, we have $g'(a) = \mathrm{e}^{a-1} - \frac12 > 0$ and $g(2) = 0$, which implies $a \ge 2$.)
On the other hand, if $a \ge 2$, letting
$$h(a, x) := \left(\frac{a}{2} x - a\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^a\right) \ln x - \mathrm{e}(x-1),$$
we have, for all $x\ge 1$,
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial a} = (x/2 - \mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^a) \ln x \ge 0$$
which results in $h(a, x) \ge h(2, x) = (x - 2\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^2)\ln x - \mathrm{e}(x-1)$.
We can prove that $(x - 2\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^2)\ln x - \mathrm{e}(x-1) \ge 0$ on $x \ge 1$. It suffices to prove that
$$F(x) := \ln x - \frac{\mathrm{e}(x - 1)}{x - 2\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^2} \ge 0.$$
We have
$$F'(x) = \frac{(\mathrm{e} - x)(\mathrm{e}^3 - 4\mathrm{e}^2 + 4\mathrm{e} - x)}{x(x - 2\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^2)^2}.$$
We have $F'(x) > 0$ on $[1, \mathrm{e}^3 - 4\mathrm{e}^2 + 4\mathrm{e})$, and $F'(x) < 0$ on $(\mathrm{e}^3 - 4\mathrm{e}^2 + 4\mathrm{e}, \mathrm{e})$,
and $F'(x) > 0$ on $(\mathrm{e}, \infty)$.
Also, $F(1) = 0$ and $F(\mathrm{e}) = 0$. Thus, we have $F(x) \ge 0$ on $x \ge 1$. Thus, $h(a, x) \ge 0$ on $x \ge 1$.
As a result, $(\frac{a}{2}x - a\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^a)\ln x \ge \mathrm{e}(x - 1)$ holds for all $x \ge 1$, if and only if, $a \ge 2$.


If you look at it from a differential perspective, you are looking to find $a$ less or greater than $a_T$ such that RHS is tangent to LHS when $a_T$.

Let $f(x) = (\cfrac{a}{2}x-ae+e^a)\ln x$ and $g(x) = e(x - 1)$. We first observe that point that $f(1) = g(1) = 0$ and this is important.
For $a > 0$ and $x > 1$, both $f, g$ are injective so $x = 1$ is the only solution. Then the solution lies in figuring out $a_T = \{k: f'(1) = g'(1)\}$
$$\implies e^a  + \frac{a}{2} - ae = e
\\\Rightarrow 2e^a + a(1 - 2e) = 2e
\\\Rightarrow e^a = -\left(\frac{1 - 2e}{2}\right)\left(a - \frac{2e}{1 - 2e}\right)
\\\Rightarrow a_T = \frac{2e}{1 - 2e} - W_{0, -1}\left( \frac{e^{\frac{2e}{1 - 2e}}}{1 - 2e} \right)\,,\quad -1/e < \frac{e^{\frac{2e}{1 - 2e}}}{1 - 2e} < 0$$
Here, $W_{0, -1}$ are the real branches of the product-log function. I doubt there is an elementary form to the solution. WA approximations show $W_0 \approx - 0.15\,,\quad W_{-1} \approx -3.18$. So for $a > 0$, we accept $\frac{2e}{1 - 2e} - W_{-1} \approx 1.95$ or
$$a \in \left[\frac{2e}{1 - 2e} - W_{-1}\left( \frac{e^{\frac{2e}{1 - 2e}}}{1 - 2e} \right), \infty\right)$$
